# FriendlyID with globalize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, globalize

My `Post` model uses `translates` method from `globalize` gem and `friendly_id` to gerenate more user friendly urls.

When I create my post in my native language it gets added. Accessing it after switching to `en` locale makes it fallback for the native translation, as it does not have any. How can I achieve this with `friendlyID`? I mean, the `slug` for current locale is generated correctly, but it is still `nil` for the other locales.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    # Translations
    translates :title, :body, :slug
    # FriendlyID
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding globalize to the friendly_id

```
friendly_id :title, :use => [:slugged, :globalize]
```